# Comparar si 2 pedidos son clones (diferente ID) SQL

Tags: sql, tsql

Resulta que tengo una tabla que tiene la cabecera de un pedido y el detalle del mismo.

En ciertas ocasiones pasa que un pedido se clona (lo cual genera un id diferente para cada uno), por ejemplo, el cliente 100 se le genero el pedido con el id 134 y 135 (el cual el 134 esta esta repetido y no deberia existir), yo puedo comparar la los clientes, el dia sea igual.

**Tabla Pedidos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla PedidosDetalle**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para este ejemplo se ve que ese cliente tiene 3 pedidos ese dia pero en el detalle vemos que ninguno es igual, para que el pedido sea repetido debe cumplirse varias cosas:

1. La tabla `Pedidos` debe tener datos iguales (la hora del pedido puede
   estar un minuto en diferencia que igual es duplicado
2. Los `PedidosDetalles` del producto no son iguales (puede el `idProducto` estar igual en un pedido u
   otro pero para se duplicado deben tener las mismas lineas, mismos productos en orden, mismo peso en
   orden

Para encontrar los pedidos con cliente mayor a 1 en la tabla Pedidos estoy usando lo siguiente:

```
SELECT IdCliente , COUNT(IdCliente)
FROM Pedidos P
WHERE CAST(FechaEntrega AS DATE)='2021-05-19' AND IdEmpleado =999 AND IdCanalPedido =3 AND Eliminado =0
GROUP BY IdCliente 
HAVING COUNT(IdCliente)>1
```

Me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto bien me evalua que un cliente tuvo mas de un pedido ese dia, pero como hago para evaluar el detalle con el fin de que me diga, si son iguales, los pedidos de ese cliente tienen mismo detalle?